# How to retain UISwitch state

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I have just added a UISwitch within a cell in my settings menu and I am having issues with the switches state being reverted to on when I leave the view.

I have tried adding this code:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if autoAdjust == true {
        dupSwitch.on = true
    } else {
        dupSwitch.on = false
    }
}
```

While this does work, it isn't ideal as there is an obvious jump between states when the view appears.

How can I ensure that the switch stays in whatever position the user left it in when they leave the view?

Comment: What kind of tableView content do you use? Static cells or dynamic prototypes? If the latter, you should declare `dupSwitch.on = autoAdjust` inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that the switch stays in whatever position the user left it in when they leave the view?

Store the current state of the switch in the model class (in the Model-View-Controller sense). The value of the `autoAdjust` variable should be saved in an object that does not get unloaded with the view - i.e. in your model class.

When the view is about to appear, read the current state of the switch, and set `dupSwitch.on` to the state stored in the model.

Note: To avoid showing the process of switching, move your logic from `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillAppear`. Your code can be simplified, too - you do not need a conditional:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    dupSwitch.on = autoAdjust
}
```

Comment: Took me a while to check your response out since I have been working on other things, but you fixed my issue so thanks a lot!